# "the result being, as she had predicted, normal"?

Tags: grammaticality

I got this following sentence from a book "I had brewed her a pot of green tea and taken her temperature despite her protests, the result being, as she had predicted, normal."
Why does the author write "being". In my opinion, it should be "was", shouldn't it?

Comment: It's grammatically correct. It's an absolute construction, formed by a noun phrase and a verb ending in -ing.

Comment: In order to use 'was' there would need to be a sentence break.